# List of countries where you can play on .com sites

Tags: gaming-law

I am planning to move from Spain, where I can only play on .es sites to other country to play on .com sites.

Where can I find a list of countries where you can play on .com sites?

Comment: Why can you only play on ‘.es’ sites? Is it a government law? Or is it your internet service provider? Or is rules from the institution you you to transfer money to the site?

Comment: @k1eran It is a government law. We play with frenchs at ps

Comment: “Frenches at ps”?

Comment: Sorry I can’t help with a list! All I can say is if you move the the UK you will be ok .

Comment: There is an agreement between Spain and France to play together at .es and .fr I am thinking in moving to Malt.